# State machine coding - im stuck

Tags: c, embedded, state-machine, pic

I am trying to create a state machine but am a little lost. Please go easy on me, i've only been coding 4 months.

Im using a pic16f18325 and coding in mplab

So i think im pretty much there, i know what i want it to do, i have written diagrams etc and think i have set it up correctly. My question is how to i switch between the states? How do i change an event?

If for example i was in the maincode and i wanted to trigger the ENTER event by press of a button. Would i just write:

```
if (button == 0){ // (button has been defined already)
event = ENTER;
}
void ENTER (void){
// do some stuff
}
```

mplab is not liking the word "event" im getting a fair few errors that i dont understand:

```
main.c:33:6: error: redefinition of 'ENTER' as different kind of symbol
void ENTER (void);
     ^
main.c:26:5: note: previous definition is here
int ENTER; // for entering programming from maincode
    ^
main.c:34:6: error: redefinition of 'EXIT' as different kind of symbol
void EXIT (void);
     ^
main.c:27:5: note: previous definition is here
int EXIT; // for exiting programming and returning to maincode
    ^
main.c:35:6: error: redefinition of 'Reset' as different kind of symbol
void Reset (void);
     ^
main.c:28:5: note: previous definition is here
int Reset; // to reset the speed and return to main code
    ^
main.c:36:6: error: redefinition of 'INCREASE' as different kind of symbol
void INCREASE (void);
     ^
main.c:29:5: note: previous definition is here
int INCREASE; // to increase the speed while in programming
    ^
main.c:37:6: error: redefinition of 'DECREASE' as different kind of symbol
void DECREASE (void);
     ^
main.c:30:5: note: previous definition is here
int DECREASE; // to decrease the speed while in programming
    ^
main.c:110:36: error: function definition is not allowed here
void step_state(enum events event) { // not sure what to write here, will work it out
                                   ^
main.c:145:18: error: function definition is not allowed here
void ENTER (void){
                 ^
main.c:148:17: error: function definition is not allowed here
void EXIT (void){
                ^
main.c:151:18: error: function definition is not allowed here
void Reset (void){
                 ^
main.c:154:21: error: function definition is not allowed here
void INCREASE (void){
                    ^
main.c:157:21: error: function definition is not allowed here
void DECREASE (void){
                    ^
11 errors generated.
```

Heres my state machine coding:

```
#include "mcc_generated_files/mcc.h"
#include "mcc_generated_files/device_config.h"

int ENTER; // for entering programming from maincode
int EXIT; // for exiting programming and returning to maincode
int Reset; // to reset the speed and return to main code
int INCREASE; // to increase the speed while in programming
int DECREASE; // to decrease the speed while in programming

int events;
void ENTER (void);
void EXIT (void);
void Reset (void);
void INCREASE (void);
void DECREASE (void);


void main(void) {

enum states { // this state machine will have 2 states

    MAINCODE, // main code where it will sit most of the time
    PROGRAMMING, // and then programming which is used to change the speed
} state;

enum events { // we will have 5 events
    ENTER, // for entering programming from maincode
    EXIT, // for exiting programming and returning to maincode
    RESET, // to reset the speed and return to main code
    INCREASE, // to increase the speed while in programming
    DECREASE, // to decrease the speed while in programming
};
void step_state(enum events event) { // not sure what to write here??? what is step_state? why enum events event?
 switch(state) { // the switch is done by a change of state
 case MAINCODE: // while in maincode
  switch(event) { // and the enter event is initiated
  case ENTER: // enter programming
   state = PROGRAMMING; // to do this we change the state
   break; // break to jump into that state

  default: // if something messes up, the default instruction
   state = MAINCODE; // is to go back into the maincode
   break;
  }
  break;

 case PROGRAMMING: // while in programming state
  switch(event) { // and an event is triggered
  case EXIT: // which happens to be exit
   state = MAINCODE; // enter maincode
   break;
  case RESET:
   // add code to revert default speed value
   state = MAINCODE; // then enter maincode
   break;
  case INCREASE:
   // add code for increasing speed
   break;
  case DECREASE:
   // add code for decreasing speed
   break;

  default:
   state = MAINCODE;
   break;
  }
  break;
 }

}

if (button == 0){
event = ENTER;
}
void ENTER (void){
    state = PROGRAMMING;
}
if (button == 0){
event = EXIT;
}
void EXIT (void){
    state = MAINCODE;
}
if (button == 0 && but1 == 0){
event = Reset;
}
void Reset (void){
    value = default;
    state = MAINCODE;
}
if (but1 == 0){
event = INCREASE;
}
void INCREASE (void){
    // add code to increase speed
}
if (but2 == 0){
event = DECREASE;
}
void DECREASE (void){
    // add code to decrease speed
}
    while (1)

    {

    }
    }
```

Comment: look how to define an `enum`in a C-book

Comment: @Chronic - There's nothing in the error messages which justifies saying _mplab is not liking the word "event"_.

Comment: Just remove the useless definitions `int ENTER; …
int DECREASE;` and you'll have a bunch of errors less.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133214/is-there-a-typical-state-machine-implementation-pattern might be a very interesting read.

Comment: @MIke - he has defined an `enum` - the problem he has reused the symbols _three_ times, including in the `enum events`

Comment: The code posted is not the code that generated those errors - the line numbers do not match and the code posted has numerous other issues not reflected in the error message you have posted.  Post the real code or the real error messages to make them consistent.

Answer (score 3):

> So i think im pretty much there, [...] My question is how to i switch between the states? How do i change an event?

Surely your question is *why am I getting all these errors*?! You are clearly a lot further from *"pretty much there"* than you think.  Get valid code that compiles (i.e. learn to write valid C code) first - then ask about how to make the state machine work if it does not.  Otherwise all these other errors are just a distraction - you are not even close to *"pretty much there"* is it does not compile so you can run, test and debug it.  In fact so much so I am going to ignore your question and address the code validity. When you get the build working, ask a new question if necessary about how to make it work - or better use your debugger and figure it out for yourself.

The error messages seem pretty clear:

```
main.c:33:6: error: redefinition of 'ENTER' as different kind of symbol
void ENTER (void);
     ^
main.c:26:5: note: previous definition is here
int ENTER; // for entering programming from maincode
```

Line 33 has a definition for a *function* called `ENTER`, but `ENTER` is previously defined as an `int` variable at line 26.  It is telling you not to use the same name twice (at least not in the same scope).

In fact the symbol `ENTER` (for example - the same error for other symbols) is defined *three* times for different things:

An integer *variable*:

```
int ENTER; // for entering programming from maincode
```

A function:

```
void ENTER (void);
```

An enum *constant*:

```
enum events { // we will have 5 events
    ENTER, // for entering programming from maincode
```

It is generally a bad idea to us the same symbol name for multiple purposes and in most cases it is ambiguous so the compiler cannot determine which to use.

In this case you should use lower or CamelCase for the function names - conventionally upper case is used for *constants*.  Somewhat inconsistently you already have a `Reset()` function - you used a different naming convention elsewhere.  Caution however because `exit()` is the name of a function in the standard library.

The variable `int ENTER;` and the other similarly declared variables do not appear to be used and can probably be deleted - that then removes the ambiguity with the `enum` constants.

Apart from that, the code posted is not the code that generated the errors posted - it has numerous other issues and the line number references in the diagnostics do not align with the code posted.  Specifically:

- You have referenced to the following undeclared variables `button`, `event`, `but1`, `but2` and `value` (a particularly poor name for a variable BTW - they are all "values").
- The statement `event = Reset;` is invalid,  `event` is undefined, but context suggests that it should be an `enum events` object, in which case perhaps `RESET` was intended?
- The statement `value = default ;` is invalid because `default` is a reserved keyword for a switch case label.  It is not clear what you might have intended here, because `value` is undefined and this is the only place you have referenced it.

Comment: A suggestion could be to write `ENTER_fn` for the function, `ENTER_num` for the integer, and `ENTER_ev` for the enum

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : Indeed - a naming convention is required; I hesitate to impose or suggest one - that's a style issue.  There are many style conventions - this code ignores all of them it seems..  One danger is he has a function called `EXIT()`, simply changing to `exit()` is likely to conflict with the standard library.  The symbol names in general are poorly chosen for global symbols in any case.  I've touched on that (picking on `value` for example), but the actual question is bizarrely _"how to i switch between the states?"_ [sic]  as if that is the big issue here!

Answer (score 1):

I am not seeing an error regarding your "events" variable, and I am not aware of it being a keyword. As for the other errors, you have a few namespace issues going on. When a enum is defined, it tells the compiler to use the specified key words in place for a number to help make your source code more maintainable. The enum implicitly sets the type of these keywords to "int" making the following lines unnecessary and causes a name collision.

```
int ENTER; // for entering programming from maincode
int EXIT; // for exiting programming and returning to maincode
int Reset; // to reset the speed and return to main code
int INCREASE; // to increase the speed while in programming
int DECREASE; // to decrease the speed while in programming
```

Even with these lines removed, the compiler is getting confused because your state functions are sharing the same name as your states in your "events" enumeration. If instead you rename your state functions INCREASE_func(), DECREASE_func(), etc. it will resolve the issue. [here](https://aticleworld.com/state-machine-using-c/) is a good source of implemented state machine code in C.

Comment: The conflicting symbol names are defined _three_ times, not just two.  Renaming the functions alone is not sufficient.

Comment: answer has been edited to reflect Clifford's correction.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to redefine an already used symbol, like ENTER.. You can't name your variables the same as the methods, because the compiler is getting confused and it also doesn't make much sense for anyone

You could also use a enum type to create your state machine

```c
enum EventType {
     EVENT_NONE,
     EVENT_EXAMPLE
};

struct State {
     enum EventType last_event;  
};

int main(void) {
   struct State state = { .last_event = EVENT_NONE }

   // do what you want to do....
   {
       if (state.last_event == EVENT_EXAMPLE) {
            // do what you want 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: He already has a `enum` for the states - they have the same name as the variables and the functions too!  The variables do not appear to serve any purpose.