# Segmentation fault when implementing state pattern in C++

Tags: c++, oop, memory, design-patterns, state-pattern

I'm trying to implement `State` pattern in C++.
Here an example code:

```
#include <cstdio>

class Context;

class State {
public:
    virtual ~State() = default;

    explicit State(Context *context) : context_(context) {}

    virtual void Print() = 0;

    virtual void ChangeState() = 0;

protected:
    Context *const context_;
};

class Context {
public:
    void SwitchState(State *state) {
        delete this->current_state_;
        this->current_state_ = state;
    }

    State *GetCurrentState() const {
        return this->current_state_;
    }

private:
    State *current_state_ = nullptr;
};

class FirstState : public State {
public:
    explicit FirstState(Context *context) : State(context) {}

    ~FirstState() override {
        printf("FirstState destructed. Address: %p\n", this);
    }

    void Print() override {
        printf("First state print..\n");
    }

    void ChangeState() override;
};

class SecondState : public State {
public:
    explicit SecondState(Context *context) : State(context) {}

    void Print() override {
        printf("Second state print..\n");
    }

    void ChangeState() override;
};

void FirstState::ChangeState() {
    printf("First state changed to second state\n");
    this->context_->SwitchState(new SecondState(this->context_));
    printf("First state changed to first state\n");
    this->context_->SwitchState(new FirstState(this->context_));
    printf("First state changed to second state\n");
    this->context_->SwitchState(new SecondState(this->context_));
}

void SecondState::ChangeState() {
    this->context_->SwitchState(new FirstState(this->context_));
    this->context_->SwitchState(new SecondState(this->context_));
    this->context_->SwitchState(new FirstState(this->context_));
}

int main() {
    Context context;

    context.SwitchState(new FirstState(&context));

    context.GetCurrentState()->Print();
    context.GetCurrentState()->ChangeState();
    context.GetCurrentState()->Print();
    context.GetCurrentState()->ChangeState();

    return 0;
}
```

I have a segmentation fault error because in this implementation after calling `Context::SwitchState` from the `State`, the current state is deleted and after returning from SwitchState method I can't use `this`, but sometimes I have to.
I tried to use shared pointers, it helped a little, because I didn't get segmentation fault anymore, but for some reason destructor of the state is called anyway.
I need to create new instances of states when switching it because I need to pass some arguments to the changed state.
Also, I don't know how to solve this problem in general because all references to the state are lost after switching state, only remaining reference is `this`.
I have some bad ideas that may solve that problem, but they are ugly, for example to make `SwitchState` just saving new state, and call some `RealSwitchSavedState` at the end of every method in state. I think it would solve the problem, because in this case a reference to the state remains until the end of the method, but the code will be ugly.

Hope for your help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: "_but for some reason destructor of the state is called anyway_" You invoke `delete this->current_state_` in `Context::SwitchState`. Which.. Deletes the state, and invokes its destructor. And, since, you, essentially, from within implementations of `State::ChangeState`, delete the state, that the method is called on - dereferencing `this` of that state is UB after the deletion. Making only the first `Context::SwitchState` call non-UB. The best bet, in my opinion, is to rethink the entire architecture of relationships.

Comment: Save `this->context_` in a local variable at the top of `FirstState::ChangeState`, use that variable for subsequent `SwitchState` calls, so you don't need to touch `this`. Still a very fragile design, but it'll solve your immediate problem.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, yeah, I know why it happens, but I want to find the best solution with the same architecture, because in Java I can implement it easy, in C++ I face this problem.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks, but in a real code I need to access a full object state, but not only context. I now that I can save to a local variable data I need, but it is not a best solution

Comment: Forget your code for a minute. Can you explain in words what is supposed to happen? In particular, why is `SwitchState` logically consistent, not involving the destruction of `*this`?

Comment: @JaMiT, it is consistent only in that example to demonstrate the segmentation fault after accessing a deleted memory. It is supposed to be a simple implementation of the `State` pattern, but creating a new instance when changing a state and deleting an old one, so is a problem, because it already deleted the old one and continues to use it after returning from SwitchState

Comment: @zenno2 Stating "it is consistent" does not make it so. (Also, when formatted as `State`, the word refers to your `State` class. The name of the design pattern does not get formatted as code, as in "State design pattern".)

Comment: There are a lot of allocations here, could you not find a better solution using `std::variant`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/133214/1168342

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of allocations going on here. I'm curious if you could instead use an `std::variant` to achieve what you want.

### Implementation

```
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename... Ts> struct Overload : Ts... { using Ts::operator( )...; };
template<typename... Ts> Overload( Ts... ) -> Overload<Ts...>;

class StateBase { 
public:
    virtual void print_state( ) const = 0;
    virtual ~StateBase( ) = default;
};

class FirstState : public StateBase {
public:
    void print_state( ) const override {
        std::cout << "First state\n";
    }
};

struct SecondState : public StateBase {
public:
    void print_state( ) const override { 
        std::cout << "Second state\n";
    }
};

struct ThirdState : public StateBase {
public:
    void print_state( ) const override { 
        std::cout << "Third state\n";
    }
};

template<typename ...States>
class Fsm { 
    static_assert( ( std::is_base_of_v<StateBase, States> && ... ), "State must derive from StateBase" );

public:
    template<typename T, 
             typename En = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<StateBase, T>>>
    explicit Fsm( T initial_state ) 
        : state_{ std::move( initial_state ) }
    { }

    template<typename T, 
             typename En = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<StateBase, T>>>
    void change_state( T state ) {
        state_ = std::move( state );
    }

    template<typename T, 
         typename En = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<StateBase, T>>,
         typename ...Args>
    void change_state( Args&&... args ) {
        state_.template emplace<T>( std::forward<Args>( args )... );
    }

    void print_state( ) {
        std::visit( Overload { [ ]( const StateBase& s ) { 
            s.print_state( ); } }, state_ );
    }
private:
    std::variant<States...> state_;
};
```

### Usage

```
int main( ) {
    Fsm<FirstState, SecondState, ThirdState> fsm{ ThirdState{ } };
    // Prints Third State.
    fsm.print_state( );

    fsm.change_state( SecondState{ } );

    // Prints Second State.
    fsm.print_state( );

    fsm.change_state<FirstState>( );
    
    // Prints First State.
    fsm.print_state( );
}
```

Now I don't know exactly what your use-case is, or if this meets your requirements but you may be able to change this example to achieve your desired functionality.